# Automatically export components from build folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i am new to node and react so please forgive me if this does not sound correct.

I will try to explain this as simple as possible, but would like to know if this process can be automated somehow during a script/build process.

- I create a component called 'button.js' in lib folder.
- i added a script in the package.json file. the script is `"build": "babel lib -d build",`
- I run `npm run build` which creates a build folder with my 'button' component built.
- i export the component in an index.js file like so:

  export { default as Button } from './build/components/Button'

I am wondering if the final 2 steps can be combined into a single step i.e. build the component then export it into the index.js file? If so, could you please point me in the right direction of how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to manually manage a "monorepos", whereby you have lots of individual packages that are utilised as node modules within other packages in your solution.

I'd suggest checking out Lerna (https://github.com/lerna/lerna) which takes away some of this pain. It allows you to include internal modules into your packages as if they were normal, published npm modules.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you google on webpack. It's how most people turn a bunch of js files into a bundle.js file. This is making your website faster too, as clients only need to load 1 file.

Webpack is a big subject so look for a "webpack babel react" guide.